# Setting up Tomcat with SSL on Eclipse: "keystoreFile" has no effect

Tags: eclipse, ssl, tomcat6, keystore

I'm setting up a test environment with Tomcat6 + SSL on Eclpse

I edited the `server.xml` file (in Eclipse server folder) and uncommented the SSL connector. I then made a self signed certificate following [this how-to](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https/). Everything works fine until I keep the keystore file in my home directory but, when I try placing it in another folder and I set the "keystoreFile" parameter i get this error message at startup:

```
GRAVE: Failed to load keystore type JKS with path C:\Documents and Settings\myUser/.keystore due to C:\Documents and Settings\myUser\.keystore (Impossibile trovare il file specificato) 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents and Settings\myUser\.keystore (Impossibile trovare il file specificato)
```

It seems Tomcat doen't read my keystoreFile parameter.

here is my `server.xml` file (SSL related parts only)

```
               ...
<!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
<Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
               ...
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="C:\myPath\.keystore"
           keystorePass="******"  />
               ...
```

**Update**

I exported my project as a `.war` file and deployed it on a *stand-alone* Tomcat. It works so it must be Eclipse the cause of my problem. If it may help I'm using Eclipse Helios (Service Release 2).

Thanks.

**Epilogue**

At last it came out, thanks to Bruno, that it was Eclipse messing up with deploying files. After cleaning eclipse deploy folder everything worked.

Comment: You seem to be mixing `/` and `\ ` in `C:\Documents and Settings\mmusante.AVELCO/.keystore`. Make sure the file is readable by the Eclipse user too.

Comment: 1) The path, as is set in in server.xml, is all with "\" the mixed path is in the console error output (might be a simptom?)

2) Eclipse is running with the same user Tomcat (stand-alone) was. (I started it by shell). Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`keystoreFile` has no effect since you're using the [APR connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/apr.html#HTTPS) (`AprLifecycleListener`), which uses a different set of parameters than the [JSSE connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support).

In particular, it doesn't use `keystoreFile`, but OpenSSL-style parameters (similar to Apache Httpd's `mod_ssl` configuration): you'll need to convert your keys and certificates for it to work with the APR connector.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give a look at it, but still I don't understand why it works when deployed outside of Eclipse.

Comment: Perhaps the APR library isn't available to your installation outside Eclipse, which would make it use the JSSE implementation. There should be error messages when trying to load the APR library in this case.

Comment: I tried changing the protocol parameter to _protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"_ ,is the way to force JSSE if I well understood here (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html), but i still get the same error. When I move the keystore back to my home folder all is working fine. I'll try by upgrading Eclipse ASAP.

Comment: Make sure Eclipse uses the server configuration file you expect: it should be in the Servers project in your workspace.

Comment: I cleaned Eclipse deployment folder _"...\metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\..."_ and now it works. It seems it was Eclipse messing up with files deployment. Thanks for your help Bruno!